# Can I solve this probabilistic problem or do I need more data?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random

This problem happened to me almost 3 years ago and I just discovered this site by luck, so I want some help to know if this problem is solvable (if so, I would like to know how to solve it as well as the probabilities for each question) or if it cannot be solved due to lack of information.

**The problem of my friend**

I found my friend at university at the beginning of the 10 first days of January, February and March: January 10, February 10 and March 2.

1. What was the probability to meet at least 1 time this friend during the first 10 days for each month? (February had 28 days in 2011)
2. What would have been the probability to meet this friend at least 1 time for each month during the non-first 10 days?
3. What would have been the probability to meet this friend more than 1 time during the first 10 days of each month?

Because February had 28 days in 2011, would it be correct to say the following:

*"It would have been more probable to meet this friend during the non-first 10 days of February than during the non-first 10 days of March?*

As one more fact, I met this friend twice in March on Tuesday 15 and Friday 18.

I hope anyone can help me to solve this peculiar problem that really happened to me and got my attention since then. Thank you very much for your time and help :)